# Assert Equal an Object which has an Array within it

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

My goal is to check the similarity of an object using unittesting in python. I have this kind of object

```
class ImageModel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data #this an array
        self.name = name
        self.path = path
```

I have read that if you want to do test the similarity of an array `self.assertEqual(arr1,arr2)` you have to put `.all()` after each array. But I have to check the similarity of an object which has an array within it. For my case, it would be:

```
self.assertEqual(ImageObj1, ImageObj2)
```

But it always show that those object isn't similar, i assume the problem is at the `ImageObj.data`

so, is there any way to assert equal an array within an object?

Comment: what kind of `array` - python has `list`s( and `(frozen)set`, `dict`, `tuple`, ...). "Array"s are from other packages like array or numpy or ... which might have convenience functions to compare value equality

Comment: Unless you define `__eq__` in your class, equality is based on identity, that is, `ImageObj1 == ImageObj2` if and only if `id(ImageObj1) == id(ImageObj2)`. Python won't automatically compare two objects attribute by attribute.

Comment: @PatrickArtner the array is from reading an image with OpenCV library

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to override the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method of your class. Basically, this is the method that is called when you're using the `==` operator on an `ImageModel` instance.

Here is an example:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (
        # the two instances must be of the same class
        isinstance(other, self.__class__) and
        # compare name and path, that's straightforward
        self.name == other.name and
        self.path == other.path and
        # and compare data
        len(self.data) == len(other.data) and
        all(a == b for a, b in zip(self.data, other.data))
    )
```